# Why does getgrent return two entries for staff group on macOS?

Tags: c, macos, authentication, unix, posix

This code block prints all the user groups. Each line contains the pointer address to the `struct group`, the name and id of the group, as well as all the members of that group.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <grp.h>

int main() {
    setgrent();
    struct group *grp;
    while (grp = getgrent()) {
        printf("%p -> {%s, %s, %d}: ", grp, grp->gr_name, grp->gr_passwd, grp->gr_gid);
        for (int i = 0; grp->gr_mem[i]; i++) {
            printf("%s, ", grp->gr_mem[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    endgrent();
}
```

Particularly interesting are these two lines in the result:

```
...
0x7fc6267195f0 -> {staff, *, 20}: root, _serialnumberd,
...
0x7fc626700740 -> {staff, *, 20}: root,
...
```

Looking at `/etc/group`, however, there is only one line for `staff`.

```
staff:*:20:root
```

What could have caused the extra line for `staff` to be printed by the code block above, and why would they differ by one member?

I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Comment: Note that `getgrent` may look at information other than or in addition to to `/etc/group`, depending on how the system is configured. I don't have a MacOS system handy right now, but my guess is that when you're looking at `/etc/group` you're looking only at one of several configured data sources.

Comment: Actually, macOS only uses `/etc/group` during the startup process; after that, it's completely ignored. During normal operation, macOS's "Open Directory" system uses "dslocal" (the actual data is in property list files in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/groups/`). You can view the local group record with `dscl /Local/Default -read /Groups/staff`. It's possible you're getting another staff group entry from some other directory service; is your Mac bound to an Active Directory or LDAP domain, or anything like that?